# MS SQL SERVER the timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool

Tags: sql, sql-server

I keep getting the following error:

> the timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool

I have the database on 3 servers, 2 servers are working fine, locally is fine too.

However, on the production server, if i try to access any API i get this error.

I dont think its something related to my query, how can i fix this ?

Comment: Beside timeout, have you made any network tests? Try to see if server address is accessible, TCP port. If there is a support team ask them if there is expected the accessibility from the servers you are trying to access.

Comment: This isn't actually an issue with the SQL server, but with your (presumably ASP.NET?) web site accessing it. Check that connections are wrapped in Using statements, are adequately closed, etc. Check your connection string and see if you can add or change the `Max Pool Size` if it looks low.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the port for accessing the sql connection from your production api hosted servers to database hosted server. Might be port issue.